# How to dictionary into Firebase database using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Firebase. I am trying to save dictionary in firebase database. User can post more than one feedback. This is my firebase data formate to save feedback:[image]

I am getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Invalid key in object at path: . Keys must be non-empty and cannot contain '/' '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
```

[image]

Code: 
[image]

Comment: Please show the code you've tried

Comment: I am new in firebase so tried but could not do. please share your feedback.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I updated my question with code and error.

Comment: You've posted your code as image. Please post it as text, as it allows us to easily use it in our answer.